# Android threads not starting synchronously

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer, handler

I have a `class` in which I create a `graphview` containing words that have been taken from a song and a `mediaplayer` to play the `song` when a button is pressed. The `graph` is displaying 1 second at a time so if I change the `coordinates` by 0.1 every `100ms`. I should get the `graphview` moving as fast as the `song`.

The `audio` should `play` and the `graph` should `move` only when the button is pressed and go back to its original `position` when it is released. Now with my code the `application` is doing exatly so.

The only problem is that once it is `reset` after releasing the button, the song and `graphview` start from the same `position` as they did the first time around only now either the `graph` starts moving faster or `mediaplayer plays audio later` and I am not exactly sure why it is so and what I should do for it to run at the same time every time the `button` is held down.

```
    public class SongPlayer extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Viewport graphViewPort;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;


    private GraphView graph;
    private DataPoint[] points;
    private LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
    private int seriesNr;
    final static double graphStartingX = -0.8;
    final static double graphEndingX = 0.4;
    private double orderNr =  graphStartingX;

    private ImageButton playRecordButton;
    private Button backToSongList;
    private TextView songTitleTextView;

    private List<Pitch> pitchesList;
    List<List<Pitch>> wordsList;
    ArrayList<Audio> audioList;

    private int songIndex;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.song_player);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String songTitle = intent.getExtras().getString("TITLE");
        songIndex = intent.getExtras().getInt("INDEX");
        audioList = intent.getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("AUDIOLIST");

        //Get Textview and Button
        playRecordButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playRecord);
        songTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        backToSongList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backToSongList);

        songTitleTextView.setText(audioList.get(songIndex).getTitle());

        //Initialize pitches and words
        MakePitchesList listOfPithes = new MakePitchesList();
        MakeWordsList listOfWords = new MakeWordsList();
        pitchesList = listOfPithes.getListOfPitches();
        wordsList = listOfWords.getWordsList(pitchesList);

        //Initialize graph
        graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        initGraph();


        //ViewPort
        graphViewPort = graph.getViewport();

        //Handler
        handler = new Handler();



        playRecordButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent) {
                final int action = motionevent.getAction();

                //If button is pressed
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.i("repeatBtn", "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN");

                    //Start playing audio
                    playMedia(songIndex);

                    //Start moving graph
                    drawAndMoveGraph();


                  //If button is released, stop audio and set everything back to starting position
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Log.i("repeatBtn", "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP");
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    graphViewPort.setMinX(graphStartingX);
                    graphViewPort.setMaxX(graphEndingX);
                    graph.invalidate();
                    orderNr = graphEndingX;
                    stopAudio();

                }//end else
                return false;
            } //end onTouch
        }); //end b my button


        backToSongList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SongPlayer.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

//        StrictMode.enableDefaults();

    }

    //Move the graph by 0.1 every 100ms
    private void drawAndMoveGraph(){
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(orderNr);
                graphViewPort.setMinX(orderNr);
                graphViewPort.setMaxX(orderNr + 1);
                graph.invalidate();
                if(pitchesList.size() != orderNr){
                    orderNr = orderNr + 0.1;
                }


                handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
        };
        runnable.run();
    }

    //Initialize graph
    private void initGraph(){
        for (int i = 0; i < wordsList.size(); i++) {
            seriesNr = 0;
            points = new DataPoint[wordsList.get(i).size()];
            for (Pitch pitch: wordsList.get(i)) {
                points[seriesNr] = new DataPoint(pitch.getOccuranceTime(), pitch.getPitch());
                seriesNr++;
            }
            series = new LineGraphSeries<>(points);
            series.setThickness(15);
            graph.addSeries(series);
        }

        //VocalTestPoints
        PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new PointsGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
                new DataPoint(0, 50),
                new DataPoint(0, 75),
                new DataPoint(0, 100),
                new DataPoint(0, 125),
                new DataPoint(0, 150),
                new DataPoint(0, 175),
                new DataPoint(0, 200),
                new DataPoint(0, 225),
                new DataPoint(0, 250),
                new DataPoint(0, 275),
        });
        series.setSize(5);
        series.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        graph.addSeries(series);


        // set manual X bounds
        graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
        graph.getViewport().setMinY(-50);
        graph.getViewport().setMaxY(400);

        graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
        graph.getViewport().setMinX(graphStartingX);
        graph.getViewport().setMaxX(graphEndingX); //mitu korraga näeb

        graph.getViewport().setScrollable(true);
    }


    //Play Audio
    private void playMedia(int songIndex){
        StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
        storage.storeAudio(audioList);
        storage.storeAudioIndex(songIndex);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        //Reset so that the MediaPlayer is not pointing to another data source
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(storage.loadAudio().get(storage.loadAudioIndex()).getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });


    }

    private void stopAudio(){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();

    }
}
```

I do not know where to begin. I have been trying different `threads, runnables and async's` but the result is always the same.

Just to clarify the `graphview` looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't recommend making a video to show your problem, unless someone specifically asks. They are not popular with seasoned readers, since the links often break, and they are time-consuming to watch. If a question is not understandable without a video then it's generally thought to be off-topic.

Comment: @halfer i will keep that in mind

Comment: You are not supposed to be calling this `runnable.run();` and I don't see any other Thread here.

Comment: @Enzokie why am i not supposed to be calling `runnable.run()`. And yes there are no other Thread here but could the offset of each iteration be because there are Threads and ASyncTasks together?

Comment: The `runnable.run()` is design to be implicitly called either by Handler or Thread therefore you don't need to call it.